# Cannot reference managed service account when creating role assignment in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-security

When creating a role assignment in the Azure portal, I am able to select an Azure AD user, group, or service principle.  We have created managed service accounts in our AD Directory Services and would like to assign this MSA to a role, but managed service accounts are not listed to add.  Is it possible to add a managed service account to a role assignment in Azure?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to Managed Service Identity (for a function, web app or vm etc.)? If it's an MSI that you're trying to create a role assignment for, then you could use PowerShell.. something like.. `New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $msi.ObjectId -PrincipalId $msi.ObjectId -Id $role.Id -ResourceId [yourresourceobjectid]`

Comment: No...I can reference those without issue.  This is specifically a group managed service account.

Comment: ok makes sense, my bad.. I got it mixed up with MSI.. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Do you sync the MSA in the group to AAD?

Comment: It was created in AAD through PowerShell and is listed in the Managed Service Accounts container of the Azure AD when connecting via Active Directory Users and Computers attached to the AD Domain Services domain.  Since it's already in AAD what other sync would be needed to allow selection of this from inside the portal when assigning to a role?  I've attached a screenshot to show where the object is located.